# Getting model vertices xna + winForm project

Tags: c#, xna

First of all, I am using xna embeeded into WinForms project, which I downloaded from microsoft samples page. Now, about the project, I want to get all of the Model vertices and also all of the Model's ModelMesh vertices. I was thinking about using custom content pipeline, with `MeshContent.Geometry`, but the problem is I dont know how to use content pipeline in winForms, neither I know how to get Childrens geometry. So I tried using some other methods with `ModelMeshPart` vertex properties, but that just returns alot more vertices then there actually are. For example a simple cube has 8 vertices but that just gives alot more.

EDIT: With vertices I mean their position in `Vector3`. Like its written in .fbx if you open it with notepad.
Or is there a simpler way of getting ModelMesh size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive vertex with the same position because they have different normals, but if you only want to know the size it does not matter.

Getting the size from the ModelMeshPart vertexbuffer can be done with:

```
public void UpdateFrom( ModelMeshPart meshPart ) {
   var indices = new short[meshPart.IndexBuffer.IndexCount];
   meshPart.IndexBuffer.GetData<short>( indices );

   var vertices = new float[meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexCount 
                          * meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride/4];
   meshPart.VertexBuffer.GetData<float>( vertices );

   // Usually first three floats are position, 
   // this way don't need to know what vertex struct is used
   for ( int i=meshPart.StartIndex; i<meshPart.StartIndex + meshPart.PrimitiveCount*3; i++ ) {
     int index = (meshPart.VertexOffset + indices[i]) *
                  meshPart.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride/4;

     position = new Vector3(vertices[index] , vertices[index+1], vertices[index+2]));
     UpdateFrom(position);
  }
}

public void UpdateFrom(Vector3 point) {
   if (point.X > box.Max.X) box.Max.X = point.X;
   if (point.X < box.Min.X) box.Min.X = point.X;
   ....
}
```

Also you can use a custom processor inside the winforms sample, you only have to add the reference in the contentbuilder... the trick is referencing to the dll itself...

```
   static string[] pipelineAssemblies =
    {
        "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FBXImporter" + xnaVersion,
        "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.XImporter" + xnaVersion,
        "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter" + xnaVersion,
        "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.EffectImporter" + xnaVersion,
        Application.StartupPath + "\\SkinnedModelPipeline.dll" ,
        Application.StartupPath + "\\AnimationPipeline.dll" ,
        ....
```